# How do I use loops for automating work in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a file with data on the delivery of products to the store.I need to calculate the total number of products in the store. I want to use the knowledge of cycles to calculate the total quantity of the product in the store, but my cycle only counts the total quantity of the last product. Why?
Here is the delivery data:

```
"Day" "Cott.cheese, pcs." "Kefir, pcs." "Sour cream, pcs."
1         104           117               119
2          94           114               114
3         105           107               117
4          99           112               120
5          86           104               111
6          88           110               126
7          95           106               129
```

I put this table in the *in1* variable
Here is code:

```
s<-0 
  for (p in (2:ncol(in1))){   
     s<-sum(in1[,p]) } 
s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly your question but if you only want to add all values of your data.frame except for the first column (Day), you just need to do this:

```
sum(in1[,-1])
```

Comment: I brought one table, and if I have 10 tables, then all these actions should be automated by loops. Your method is correct, but I need a little different

Comment: @sjr_25 put all your dataframes into a list, then: `lapply(myDataframes, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the s variable each iteration, that's why it only shows the result for the last column. Try

```
s<-c()
for (p in 2:ncol(in1)) {
  s<-c(s,sum(in1[,p]))
}
```

alternatively

```
colSums(in1[,-1])
```

Comment: The first option is not very convenient, and if I want the result, that is, the total number of products multiplied by some variable(their price) and get the final answer, and not a vector of values

Comment: @sjr_25 I don't understand. Can you edit your question with your exact expected outcome? What is your actual desired result?

Comment: @user2974951Your methods give a vector of values:  671          770          836 , but I need the sum of these three numbers, that is, one finite number: 2277. I think you just need to use the sum function